# How to install MatPlotLib on Mac 10.7 in virtualenv

Tags: python, installation, matplotlib, virtualenv

Here what I try to do:

```
(SAASSenv)miki725mac:SAASSenv miki725$ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
(SAASSenv)miki725mac:SAASSenv miki725$ 
(SAASSenv)miki725mac:SAASSenv miki725$ pip install http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz
Downloading/unpacking http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz
  Downloading matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (13.3Mb): 13.3Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/matplotlib-1.0.1.tar.gz
    basedirlist is: []
    ============================================================================
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: 1.0.1
                    python: 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34)
                            [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
                  platform: darwin

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                     numpy: 1.6.0
                 freetype2: 13.0.7

    OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                    libpng: 1.4.8
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/var/folders/tk/xpmf2q_10qg45c9g_xzmvy4r0000gn/T/pip-02sOum-build/setup.py", line 162, in <module>
        if check_for_tk() or (options['build_tkagg'] is True):
      File "setupext.py", line 832, in check_for_tk
        (Tkinter.__version__.split()[-2], Tkinter.TkVersion, Tkinter.TclVersion))
    IndexError: list index out of range
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    basedirlist is: []

============================================================================

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB

            matplotlib: 1.0.1

                python: 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34)

                        [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

              platform: darwin



REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

                 numpy: 1.6.0

             freetype2: 13.0.7



OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES

                libpng: 1.4.8

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/var/folders/tk/xpmf2q_10qg45c9g_xzmvy4r0000gn/T/pip-02sOum-build/setup.py", line 162, in <module>

    if check_for_tk() or (options['build_tkagg'] is True):

  File "setupext.py", line 832, in check_for_tk

    (Tkinter.__version__.split()[-2], Tkinter.TkVersion, Tkinter.TclVersion))

IndexError: list index out of range

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/miki725/.pip/pip.log
```

Please help me. If you need any additional info, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just do

pip install -e https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git matplotlib

or clone and then install

or have a look @

http://jholewinski.org/blog/installing-matplotlib-on-os-x-10-7-with-homebrew/

but it s not a lion problem just a python 2.7.2 bug. had the same problem on a colleagues snow leopard machine

suppose your are using brew

hope this helps

Answer (score 25):

locojays line didn't work for me (osx 10.7, Python 2.7.2 via homebrew), I had to modify the command as follows:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib
```

Comment: The "+https" didn't work for me. I installed with "sudo pip-2.7 install -e git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib"

Comment: What version of pip are you using? I'm using `pip 1.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)` which I got from running `pip --version`

Comment: --version reports 'pip 1.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.1-py2.7.egg'

Comment: Odd. it seems that the `git+https://` protocol was added back in [version 0.8.2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).  Well, glad you got it working!

Comment: Odd, but not odd enough that I want to track down the reason. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

With OSX 10.7, I used the "Scipy Superpack" install script, and now I have matplotlib working fine.

http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/

It took two steps and a few minutes:

> **Install**
>
> [Download Scipy Superpack Installer for OSX 10.7](https://raw.github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack/master/install_superpack.sh)
>
> To install, open a terminal in the directory that the script is
>   located and call:
>
> `$ sh install_superpack.sh`
>
> You will be prompted for your administrator
>   password. If you have already installed the current gFortran, you can
>   bypass that package during the install process. Similarly, the
>   installation requires Git, so you will be prompted to install it if
>   you are installing remotely.