# conditionally let pip choose different version depending on platform

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have this in my requirements.txt 
`matplotlib==1.3.1`.

This will install on linux, but not on mac, see: [How to install MatPlotLib on Mac 10.7 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936884/how-to-install-matplotlib-on-mac-10-7-in-virtualenv)

If want to say something like

```
if platform==mac: matplotlib==1.3.1
else: -e git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib
```

But obviouly can't as pip doesn't understand if. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about make multiple requirements files?

- base requirements file that does not contain any `matplotlib` line.
- mac version (Use this on mac):

  ```
  -r base_requirements.txt
  -e git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib
  ```
- non-mac version:

  ```
  -r base_requirements.txt
  matplotlib==1.3.1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078063/302521 and this script: https://gist.github.com/pombredanne/72130ee6f202e89c13bb
Using the same approach that @falsetru proposed, you can use a single shell script and select various requirement files based on some condition such as os, arch or anything else you want.